# JavaFX8: TableView row added changes all previous rows to same values?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I’m using JavaFX 8 and JDK 1.8.0_77 in IntelliJ with SceneBuilder.  I created the Message Center GUI with SceneBuilder.  I have a TableView with five columns, ***Start Date***, ***End Date***, ***Message***, ***Category*** and ***Status***.  The values are entered via controls and saved in the ***Message Object*** when the ***Add*** button is clicked.  The ***Message*** object is added to the ***msgTableView*** with ***msgTableView.getItems().add(message)***.

[image: Message Center window]

The problem is as I add a message object to the bottom row, all the previous rows change to the last row; the number of rows is correct but all the rows are the same.

My Message object code:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {


public static LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
public static LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();
public static String newMsg;
public static String status;
public static String category;

public void Messages(LocalDate StartDate, LocalDate EndDate, String NewMsg, String Status, String Category){
    this.startDate = StartDate;
    this.endDate = EndDate;
    this.newMsg = NewMsg;
    this.status = Status;
    this.category = Category;
}

// --------------Getters and Setters----------------------------

public LocalDate getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public LocalDate getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getNewMsg() {
    return newMsg;
}

public void setNewMsg(String newMsg) {
    this.newMsg = newMsg;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String type) {
    this.category = type;
}
```

The critical Controller code is:

```
    // TableView --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@FXML
private TableView<Message> msgTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Message, LocalDate> StartDateTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Message, LocalDate> EndDateTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Message, String> MessageTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Message, String> CategoryTableCol;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Message, String> StatusTableCol;

@FXML
private DatePicker startDatePicker;

@FXML
private DatePicker endDatePicker;

@FXML
private TextField msgTextField;

@FXML
private ComboBox categoryComboBox;

@FXML
private Button addButton;

@FXML
private Button deleteButton;

@FXML
private Button editButton;


public void saveLine() {

    Message message = new Message();

    message.setStartDate(startDatePicker.getValue());
    message.setEndDate(endDatePicker.getValue());
    message.setNewMsg(msgTextField.getText());
    message.setStatus("active"); 
    message.setCategory(categoryComboBox.getValue().toString());

    msgTableView.getItems().add(message);

    clearLine();
}

public void clearLine() {

    System.out.println( "\nEntered clearAll() " );

    startDatePicker.setValue(null);
    endDatePicker.setValue(null);
    msgTextField.clear();
    categoryComboBox.setValue("Category");
}
```

Comment: Short answer - `static` variables are shared among all instances of a class. Long answer - see flagged question.

Comment: I moved the Static Variables to the Controller and used Private variables in the Message.java class and my three days of suffering were over - hard lesson learned.  THANKS.